# Mongodb pipeline is breaking due to large number of data

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, php-mongodb

I have written the below pipeline for fetching data from multiple tables by performing lookup commands. The below query was working fine till yesterday without $step20. As soon as data grew in size, the clients kept adding certificates to the students and employees, the below query started breaking throwing the error message"Total size of documents in studentTbl matching pipeline's $lookup stage exceeds 104857600 bytes". Then after doing so R & D, I found $step20 which I have added to the below pipeline, but it still throws the same error message.

```
    $page = (int) $this->page;
    $length = (int) $this->length;

    $param = preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $this->search);
    $arg = trim($param);

    $dateFormat = "%m/%d/%Y";
    if ($this->sessionDateFormat === "m-d-Y") {
        $dateFormat = "%m/%d/%Y";
    } elseif ($this->sessionDateFormat === "d-m-Y") {
        $dateFormat = "%d/%m/%Y";
    } elseif ($this->sessionDateFormat === "Y-m-d") {
        $dateFormat = "%Y/%m/%d";
    }

    $sortby = $this->sortby;
  
    switch ($sortby) {
        case 0:
            $sortparam = "UsedFor";
            break;
        case 1:
            $sortparam = "Type";
            break;
        case 2:
            $sortparam = "convertedPid";
            break;
        case 3:
            $sortparam = "certificateNo";
            break;
        case 4:
            $sortparam = 'insensitiveFirstName';
            break;
        case 5:
            $sortparam = "insensitiveAssignedByCombinedFirstLastName";
            break;
        case 6:
            $sortparam = "dateAndTime";
            break;

        default:
            $sortparam = "dateAndTime";
            break;
    }

    $skip = ($page);


    $step1 =  ['$lookup' => [
                'from' => 'EmployeesTbl',
                'localField' => '_id',
                'foreignField' => 'CertificatesDetails.documentType',
                'as' => 'employeeArray'
            ]];

    $step2 =  ['$lookup' => [
                'from' => 'studentTbl',
                'localField' => '_id',
                'foreignField' => 'certificates_details.documentType',
                'as' => 'studentArray'
            ]];

    $step3 =  [
                '$project' => [
                  "_id" => 1.0,
                  "UsedFor" => 1.0,
                  "Type" => 1.0,
                  "Code" => 1.0,
                  "Description" => 1.0,
                  "schoolId" => 1.0,
                  
                  "employeeArray._id" => 1.0,
                  "employeeArray.FirstName" => 1.0,
                  "employeeArray.LastName" => 1.0,
                  "employeeArray.EmployeeNumber" => 1.0,
                  "employeeArray.CertificatesDetails" => 1.0,
                  
                  "studentArray._id" => 1.0,
                  "studentArray.first_name" => 1.0,
                  "studentArray.last_name" => 1.0,
                  "studentArray.uploadsFolder" => 1.0,
                  "studentArray.certificates_details" => 1.0,
                  "studentArray.registration_temp_perm_no" => 1.0
                ]
             ];

    $step4 =  array(
        '$match' => [
            'schoolId' => new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID($this->schoolId),
            '$or' => [
                ['employeeArray' => ['$not' => ['$size' => 0]]],
                ['studentArray' => ['$not' => ['$size' => 0]]]
            ]
        ]
    ); 

    $step5 =  ['$unwind' => [ 
                'path' => '$employeeArray',
                'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays' => true 
            ]];
            
    $step6 =  ['$unwind' => [
                'path' => '$studentArray',
                'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays' => true
            ]];   

    $step7 =  [
                '$project' => [
                    "_id" => 1.0,
                    "UsedFor" => 1.0,
                    "Type" => 1.0,
                    "Code" => 1.0,
                    "Description" => 1.0,
                    "schoolId" => 1.0,
                    "employeeArray" => 1.0,
                    "studentArray" => 1.0,
                    "userId" =>  [
                        '$cond' => [
                            'if' => [
                                '$eq' => ['$UsedFor', 'Employee'],
                            ],
                            'then' => '$employeeArray._id',
                            'else' => '$studentArray._id'
                        ]
                    ],
                    "firstName" =>  [
                        '$cond' => [
                            'if' => [
                                '$eq' => ['$UsedFor', 'Employee'],
                            ],
                            'then' => '$employeeArray.FirstName',
                            'else' => '$studentArray.first_name'
                        ]
                    ],
                    "lastName" =>  [
                        '$cond' => [
                            'if' => [
                                '$eq' => ['$UsedFor', 'Employee'],
                            ],
                            'then' => '$employeeArray.LastName',
                            'else' => '$studentArray.last_name'
                        ]
                    ],
                    "pid" =>  [
                        '$cond' => [
                            'if' => [
                                '$eq' => ['$UsedFor', 'Employee'],
                            ],
                            'then' => '$employeeArray.EmployeeNumber',
                            'else' => '$studentArray.registration_temp_perm_no'
                        ]
                    ],
                    "certificatesDetails" =>  [
                        '$cond' => [
                            'if' => [
                                '$eq' => ['$UsedFor', 'Employee'],
                            ],
                            'then' => '$employeeArray.CertificatesDetails',
                            'else' => '$studentArray.certificates_details'
                        ]
                    ],
                    "uploadsFolder" =>  [
                        '$cond' => [
                            'if' => [
                                '$eq' => ['$UsedFor', 'Employee'],
                            ],
                            'then' => "",
                            'else' => '$studentArray.uploadsFolder'
                        ]
                    ],
                ]
            ];  
            
    $step8 =  [
                '$project' => [
                    "_id" => 1.0,
                    "UsedFor" => 1.0,
                    ....
                        '$filter' => [
                            'input' => '$certificatesDetails',
                            'as' => 'object',
                            'cond' => [ 
                                  '$eq' => ['$$object.documentType', '$_id'],
                                ]
                            ]
                      ],                
                ]
            ];  
            
    $step9 = [
                '$project' => [
                    "_id" => 1.0,
                    "UsedFor" => 1.0,
                    "Type" => 1.0,
                    "Code" => 1.0,
                    "Description" => 1.0,
                    "schoolId" => 1.0,
                    .....
                   // "certificatesDetails" => 1.0,
                    "currentCertificateDetails" => 1.0
                ]
            ];       
            
    $step10 = ['$unwind' => [
                'path' => '$currentCertificateDetails',
                'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays' => true
            ]];    
            
    
    $step11 =  [
                '$project' => [
                    "_id" => 1.0,
                    "UsedFor" => 1.0,
                    "Type" => 1.0,
                    "Code" => 1.0,
                     ......
                   .....
                ]
            ];       
    

      $step12 =  ['$lookup' => [
                'from' => 'userTbl',
                'localField' => 'createdBy',
                'foreignField' => '_id',
                'as' => 'createdByArray'
            ]];   
            
    
      $step13 = array(
                '$match' => [
                    'isActive' => true 
                ]
            );    
         
       $step14 =   [
                '$project' => [
                    "_id" => 1.0,
                    //"studentArray" => 1.0,
                      ....             
                     .....
                    "toShow" => 1.0,
                    "isActive" => 1.0,
                    "createdByArray" =>  1.0,
                    "userActualId" => '$createdByArray.uid',
                    "certificateNo" => 1
                ]
            ];      
            
     $step15 = ['$lookup' => [
                'from' => 'EmployeesTbl',
                'localField' => 'userActualId',
                'foreignField' => '_id',
                'as' => 'userActualArray'
            ]];


     $step16 = ['$unwind' => [
        'path' => '$userActualArray',
        'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays' => true
      ]];       
     
      $step17 =  [
                '$project' => [
                    "_id" => 1.0,
                    "UsedFor" => 1.0,
                    "Type" => 1.0,
                    "Code" => 1.0,
                    "certificateNo" => 1,
                    "Description" => 1.0,
                    "schoolId" => 1.0,
                    //"employeeArray" => 1.0,
                    //"studentArray" => 1.0,
                 ...                       
                    "userActualId" => 1.0,
                    "assignedByFirstName" => '$userActualArray.FirstName',
                    "assignedByLastName" => '$userActualArray.LastName',
                    "certificateNo" => 1
                ]
            ];  
            
        $step18 = [
                '$project' => [
                    "_id" => 1.0,
                    "UsedFor" => 1.0,
                    "Type" => 1.0,
                    "Code" => 1.0,
                    "Description" => 1.0,
                    "schoolId" => 1.0,
                  //  "employeeArray" => 1.0,
                  //  "studentArray" => 1.0,
                    "userId" =>  1.0,
                    "certificateNo" => 1,
                    "firstName" => 1.0,
                    "lastName" => 1.0,
                    "firstLastNameCombined" => 1.0,
                    ...
                    "toShow" => 1.0,
                    "isActive" => 1.0,
                    "createdByArray" =>  1.0,
                    "userActualArray" => 1.0,
                    "userActualId" => 1.0,
                    "assignedByFirstName" => 1.0,
                    "assignedByLastName" => 1.0,
                    "assignedByCombinedFirstLastName" => array('$concat' => array('$assignedByFirstName', ' ', '$assignedByLastName')),
                    "certificateNo" => 1
                ]
           ];

            $step19 = [
                '$project' => [
                    "_id" => 1.0,
                    "UsedFor" => 1.0,
                    "Type" => 1.0,
                    ....
                    "certificateNo" => 1
                ]
            ];

    $querySearch = [
        '$or' => array(
            array("UsedFor" => new MongoDB\BSON\Regex($arg, 'i')),
            array("Type" => new MongoDB\BSON\Regex($arg, 'i')),
            array("pid" => new MongoDB\BSON\Regex($arg, 'i')),
            array("certificateNo" => new MongoDB\BSON\Regex($arg, 'i')),
            array("dateAndTimeString" => new MongoDB\BSON\Regex($arg, 'i')),
            array("insensitiveCombinedFirstLastName" => new MongoDB\BSON\Regex($arg, 'i')),
            array("insensitiveAssignedByCombinedFirstLastName" => new MongoDB\BSON\Regex($arg, 'i'))
        )
    ];


    $step20 = [
        'allowDiskUse' => true
    ];

    $searchCommand = ['$match' => $querySearch];

    $sortCommand = array('$sort' => array($sortparam => ($this->sortbyparam == 'asc') ? -1 : 1));

    $skipCommand =  array('$skip' => $skip);
    
    $limitCommand = array('$limit' => $length);

    $cursor = iterator_to_array($this->db->certificateTypeTbl->aggregate(array($step1, $step2, $step3,  $step4,  $step5,  $step6, $step7, $step8, $step9, $step10, $step11, $step12, $step13, $step14, $step15, $step16, $step17, $step18, $step19, $searchCommand, $sortCommand, $skipCommand, $limitCommand), $step20));
```

Please note that there are a lot of students in our database. (above 5000). I am not able to find any better solution. Kindly help!!!

Comment: You have reached the 100 MB memory limit. Try setting `allowDiskUse` to true. https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/reference/command/aggregate/#std-label-aggregate-cmd-allowDiskUse Details on memory restrictions: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/core/aggregation-pipeline-limits/

Comment: I have already tried that too. It still throws the same error.... Please help me... How will I increase memory limit for the above pipeline